# How to get the (static) type of an expression in Scala?

Tags: scala, code-generation, typeof, scala-macros, scalameta

Does Scala have any equivalent to GCC's `typeof`[extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)? (Or C++ `decltype`?)

I'm generating code that references some external code (which may not be available yet), and I need a way to reference the type of that code in a method definition

For singleton objects, I could use `Foo.type`, but if `Foo` is an arbitrary expression, that doesn't work.

**Update:**

Here is a simplified example that shows the problem:

```scala
def f(x: typeof(Foo))(implicit M: Monoid[typeof(Foo)]) =
  M.append(Foo, M.append(x, Foo))
```

The code I am working on doesn't know anything about `Foo` other than that it is a string representation of a Scala expression. It is outputting the above code to a `.scala` file which is to be later compiled as part of a separate project.

Of course the `typeof(Foo)` bits don't work. Using `Foo.type` would work only if `Foo` is a singleton.

Basically, I want to know if there is something I could substitute in place of `typeof(Foo)` that would work for arbitrary Scala expressions.

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you want? Maybe an example on how that should work? Also, how are you generating the code? Macros? Script? Scalameta?

Comment: Additionally to @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez's questions, when do you generate code, at compile time or runtime? When does external code ("which may not be available yet") become available, at compile time or runtime? There're type ascription `1 : Int`, `asInstanceOf`, `typeOf`/`weakTypeOf`, `c.typecheck` ...

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Added an example. The code is actually being generated from a Purescript script, long before Scala compilation is started.

Comment: @DmytroMitin The code is being generated before it is compiled. If we were to integrate into SBT we would be using `sourceGenerators`.

Comment: I think you are reinventing either **Macros** or **ScalaMeta**. Have you toke a look to them?

Comment: @aij Actually I guess this is close to what was asked

`class TypeOf[A](a: A) {
  type T = A
}`

`val tp = new TypeOf(Foo)`

`def f(x: tp.T)(implicit M: Monoid[tp.T]) = M.append(Foo, M.append(x, Foo))`

Answer (score 4):

In Scala there is no `typeof` of that sort.

We can try to modify the method adding type parameter

```
def f[F](foo: F)(x: F)(implicit M: Monoid[F]) =
  M.append(foo, M.append(x, foo))
```

and call it like `f(Foo)(...)`, where `Foo` is the expression to be substituted, then `F` should be inferred upon compilation.

Otherwise I can imagine the following workflow. We could generate string represenation of the type of expression `Foo` from string represenation of `Foo` itself with Scalameta's [SemanticDB](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html) and then insert string representation of expression `Foo` and this generated string represenation of the type.

One more option is to generate tree with [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class generate(foo: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro generateMacro.impl
}

object generateMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val str: String = c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new generate($s)" => c.eval[String](c.Expr(s))
    }
    val tree = c.typecheck(c.parse(str))
    val tpe = tree.tpe.widen
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods def $name[..$_](...$_): $_ = $_" :: _ =>
        q"""
            $mods def $name(x: $tpe)(implicit M: Monoid[$tpe]): $tpe =
              M.append($tree, M.append(x, $tree))
          """
    }
  }
}

@generate("1 + 1")
def f(): Unit = ()
// def f(x: Int)(implicit M: Monoid[Int]): Int = M.append(2, M.append(x, 2))
```

https://github.com/travisbrown/type-provider-examples/

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typeproviders.html

---

Actually I guess this is close to what was asked

```
class TypeOf[A](a: A) {
  type T = A
}

val tp = new TypeOf(Foo)

def f(x: tp.T)(implicit M: Monoid[tp.T]) = M.append(Foo, M.append(x, Foo))
```

Comment: "It would be a type depending on arbitrary value, so we would have fully dependent types in Scala." It wouldn't depend on value, only on the expression's static type, which is fine... but it still doesn't exist in Scala.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Actually I guess `class TypeOf[A](a: A) {
  type T = A
}` `val tp = new TypeOf(Foo)` `def f(x: tp.T)(implicit M: Monoid[tp.T]) = M.append(Foo, M.append(x, Foo))` is close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference class for the type you want to use? Else define a custom class, and use:

```
classOf [Class_Name]
```

is equivalent typeOf

And if you re trying to know the class of your custom object, then use:

```
object_name.getClass
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `classOf[Class_Name]` is an expression, not a type. What I want is something equivalent to `Class_Name` but without needing to know the type in advance.

Comment: I need some more details to help you on this.


`object_name.getClass().getName` 

gives you the class name.

And to parse the satement, you can use 

`classOf [Any]` if you donot know the class during compile time.