# The opposite of compiletime.constValue[T] in Scala 3

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

If we have a `transparent inline def f(...): Boolean = ...`, is it possible to convert the result of `f` to `true` or `false` **types**, assuming the result of `f` is known at compile-time? I would like to use those types in an implicit search.

For example,

```
given [A](using f(5) <:< true): MyTypeClass with ...
```

However, the problem is that `f(5)` is a value, not a type. So the above code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the closest is

```
val x = TypeOf(f(5))

given [A](using x.T <:< A): MyTypeClass[A] = ???

class TypeOf[A](a: A):
  type T = A

trait MyTypeClass[A]

transparent inline def f(inline i: Int): Any = inline i match
  case 5 => true
  case _ => "a"

summon[MyTypeClass[Boolean]] // compiles
summon[MyTypeClass[String]] // doesn't compile
```

Unfortunately we can't replace `(using x.T <:< A)` with `(using TypeOf(f(5)).T <:< A)` because path-dependent types must have stable prefix even in Scala 3.

[How to get the (static) type of an expression in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991021/how-to-get-the-static-type-of-an-expression-in-scala)

[type annotations overriden by inferred expression type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220935/type-annotations-overriden-by-inferred-expression-type)

[Scala Defining Custom Type - Type Mismatch Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344603/scala-defining-custom-type-type-mismatch-error)